# Flutter - Changing SVG icon color

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I have a Flutter app, which has a `BottomNavigationBar`, and its icons are made in svg. When selecting an icon from that bar, only the text changes color, the svg icons remain the same color.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: widget._colors.orange,
        unselectedItemColor: widget._colors.grey,
        items: _iconNavBar,
        currentIndex: _index,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: onTap,
      ),
```

Example of how the `BottomNavigationBarItem()` is doing

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
      'svgs/home.svg',
    ),
    label: 'Home')
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just try to use `activeIcon:` in `bottomBarItem` and there put your default icon with `color`.
Example:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
              label: 'label',
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  iconPath,
              ),
              activeIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  iconPath,
                  color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: The `color` tag is now depreciated. To change the color of the icon use this: `colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.blue, BlendMode.srcIn),`

Comment: @L.Goyal Whenever I use Blendmode.srcIn the svg icon becomes a filled square. How can I fix that? I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @VishnuER That majorly depends on the icon you are using. I use icons from Google / FontAwesome & I rarely encounter this issue. This happens because of the way the icon is created.

Comment: @VishnuER You can try wrapping 'SvgPicture' widget with 'Transform.scale(scale: 0.9999, child: child)'

Answer (score 20):

If you want to add color to an SVG image in your Flutter app using the flutter_svg package, you can achieve this effortlessly using the *colorFilter* property.

```
SvgPicture.asset(
'path to svg eg: assets/icons/svg/wrong_option.svg',
colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.srcIn),   
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Impeller` in your app, as Antialiasing does not seem to work with Impeller rendering you can wrap `SvgPicture` widget with `Transform.scale(scale: 0.9999, child: child)`

```
Transform.scale(
        scale: 0.99,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'svg path',
          colorFilter:
              ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black, BlendMode.srcIn),
        ),
      ),
```

[Refrences](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/948#issuecomment-1598166520)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I've made it work. There could be better ways than this.

```dart
BlocBuilder<NavbarBloc, NavbarState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            onTap: (index) {
              BlocProvider.of<NavbarBloc>(context).add(OnTap(index));
            },
            currentIndex: state.index,
            selectedItemColor: const Color(0xffFF7BC3),
            unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xffC0C0C0),
            showUnselectedLabels: true,
            selectedLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
              fontSize: 10.sp,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              letterSpacing: -0.24,
            ),
            unselectedLabelStyle: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
              fontSize: 10.sp,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              letterSpacing: -0.24,
            ),
            items: BlocProvider.of<NavbarBloc>(context)
                .navItems
                .asMap()
                .entries
                .map((e) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                      e.value.$1,
                      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                        state.index == e.key
                            ? const Color(0xffFF7BC3)
                            : const Color(0xffc0c0c0),
                        BlendMode.srcIn,
                      ),
                    ),
                    label: e.value.$2))
                .toList(),
        );
      },
    );
```

There are some decorations I've omitted from the code above. This is how it looks:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.srcIn)
ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.modulate)
ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.srcATop)
```

Answered by [eli1stark](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/828)